# Paraview: Store representation in VTK-XML

Tags: xml, vtk, paraview

I'm not 100% sure this belongs on SO, please move if not.

Anyway, I have a program whose data I want to store as a VTK-XML, so that it can be viewed in ParaView. ParaView defaults to certain representations of data (Surface, Wireframe, Points, Slice, etc.) depending on the file type.
Is there an attribute in the XML that I can set, which tells/forces ParaView to choose a certain representation?
Specifically, my ParaView 5.2 defaults to "Slice" for ImageData, but I'd rather have "Surface With Edges", because at that stage, it's purely geometrical/topological data. Therefore, no CellData/PointData is available for texturing and that's the error ParaView outputs.

Here's a very simple example XML which causes that issue:

```
<VTKFile type="ImageData" version="0.1" byte_order="LittleEndian">
    <ImageData WholeExtent="0 3 0 3 0 0"
    Origin="0 0 0" Spacing="0.5 0.5 0">
    </ImageData>
</VTKFile>
```

Comment: There is no way to specify the desired representation in the VTK XML file format. VTK doesn't "know" about ParaView, so it wouldn't make sense to have such an element/attribute in the XML. There is not currently a way to set the default representation for a data set type, unfortunately (https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/-/issues/15313)

BTW, ParaView 5.8 does not produce any errors when loading this data file.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. Thanks for your detailed answer :)